# Grab Post Types Based on ID of another Post Type

Tags: wordpress, foreach, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

So I have a client who has workers who get reviews. The client wants to have their bio pages separate from their review pages. I have a page template for bios and for reviews.

Each testimonial has an ACF relationship field where the client can choose the bio of who the review is about. These reviews will be manually entered by the client as they are specific to their own clients.

How can I grab reviews that are assigned a specific person and then display them on that persons separate review page.

I tried this and it gives me back an array but sadly it is every test review I entered and not just the two assigned to the specific person

```
<?php 

                    /*
                    *  Query posts for a relationship value.
                    *  This method uses the meta_query LIKE to match the string "123" to the database value a:1:{i:0;s:3:"123";} (serialized array)
                    */

                    $subject = the_field('testimonial_broker', $post->ID);

                    $testimonials = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'testimonial_broker', 
                                'value' => $subject,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            )
                        )
                    ));
                    var_dump($testimonials);
                    ?>
                    <?php if( $testimonials ): ?>

                        <?php foreach( $testimonials as $testimonial ): ?>
                            <?php 

                            $photo = get_field('testimonial_logo', $testimonial->ID);
                            $testimonial_text = get_field('testimonial_body', $testimonial->ID);

                            var_dump($photo);
                            var_dump($testimonial_text);

                            ?>
                            <div class="row testimonial align-items-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-3">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-9 bg-offwhite">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $subject = get_field('testimonial_broker', post->id); //returns post     object

$testimonials = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                        'post_per_page' => -1, 
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                                          array(
                                                                  'testimonial_broker', // name of custom field
                                                                   'value' => '"' . $subject->id. '"',
                                                                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                                            )
                           )

));
```

I am looking into the explanation of why you have to wrap it in quotes. Using LIKE appends wildcards to the string to match multiple but it's not clear why the quotes work and a simple equals will not.

Comment: Trying either way still returns every review and not just ones that have the related field. Close though.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula testimonial field is a relationship field but what do you have it set to return? it can return and object or ID. Have it return the ID and try again. do a var_dump($subject); to be sure of what is returned